# Magento 2.3 Custom Product Grid in custom module

Tags: magento2

I want to show  a Product grid based on the specific attribute filter in my custom module , how to achieve this , i have tried with extending the product_listing.xml, nothing worked , new to magento 2.3 , kindly help me

Comment: any guidance will be helpful